# Get date of max hours worked

Tags: mysql

Tables:
Employee   ( ID , Name )
EmployeeHours  (  EmployeeID  ,Date, Hours )

**This is my requirement:**

> Write a sql  for following results for a year   EmployeeID ,
> TotalHoursWorked , Date and Hours ( Date and Hours when Employee worked
> most )

I wrote the following query:

```
select e.id, e.name, sum(eh.hours) as totalHoursWorked, max(hours) hour
from shoplist.emp e, shoplist.empHours eh where e.id = eh.empId 
group by eh.empId;
```

I am able to get id, name, totalHoursWorked with maxHour but I am a bit confused how to get the date of the max hours. Can someone help me with this?

**Sample Data:**

Emp Table

```
id, name
'1','akhil'
'2','preethi'
'3','gopi'
```

Emp Hours Table

```
id, empId, hours, date
'1','1','3','2022-05-12'
'2','1','5','2022-05-11'
'3','1','4','2022-05-10'
'4','2','2','2022-05-12'
'5','2','4','2022-05-10'
'6','3','3','2022-05-09'
'7','3','5','2022-05-08'
```

**Expected**

```
id, name, totalHoursWorked, maxHours, maxHourDate
'1','akhil','12','5','2022-05-12'
'2','preethi','6','4','2022-05-12'
'3','gopi','8','5','2022-05-09'
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Could you provide text format instead of images? thanks

Comment: Sample data must be provided a textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and must be accompanied with desired output for this data.

Comment: *I wrote the following query* Incomplete grouping. If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode will be enabled (for example during server version update) then the query will fail. Replace your GROUP BY clause with `GROUP BY e.id, e.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use you query result in join with the original table

```
  select distinct eh1.empId, eh1.date, t.hours, t.name, t.totalHoursWorked 
  from shoplist.empHours eh1 inner join ( 
    select e.id, e.name, sum(eh.hours) as totalHoursWorked, max(eh.hours) hours 
    from shoplist.emp e 
    inner join shoplist.empHours eh on e.id = eh.empId group by eh.empId 
  ) t on t.id = eh1.empId AND t.hours = eh1.hours
```

for the same use with several dates with the same numbers of hours you couldselect the max or the minn this way

```
  select  eh1.empId, max(eh1.date), t.hours, t.name, t.totalHoursWorked 
  from shoplist.empHours eh1 inner join ( 
    select e.id, e.name, sum(eh.hours) as totalHoursWorked, max(eh.hours) hours 
    from shoplist.emp e 
    inner join shoplist.empHours eh on e.id = eh.empId group by eh.empId 
  ) t on t.id = eh1.empId AND t.hours = eh1.hours
  group by eh1.empId
```

Comment: After making some changes for your query its working @scaisEdge

Comment: select distinct eh1.empId, eh1.date, t.hours, t.name, t.totalHoursWorked from shoplist.empHours eh1
inner join  (
  select e.id, e.name, sum(eh.hours) as totalHoursWorked, max(eh.hours) hours
  from shoplist.emp e
  inner join shoplist.empHours eh on  e.id = eh.empId 
  group by eh.empId
) t on t.id = eh1.empId AND t.hours = eh1.hours;

Comment: I think this fails when we have same hours multiple times for same user

Comment: answer update with a suggestion for the same user with several dates ..